# Amazon S3 Access Denied when reading S3 bucket files with "+" sign

Tags: amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I am working on a rails application for which I use carrierwave with fog storage. I have a couple of fields in my form where users can submit an app its(Name, short & long description, image field). The name of the uploaded file is gotten from the name that is field in the 'Name' field of my form.

For example, when I upload a file with the name `Notepad` everything works fine and the image gets displayed on my apps page. However when I upload an image with the name `Notepad++` in the form field it uploads successfully to Amazon but I get a broken image. Viewing its source and trying to open its url produces an error

```
<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>0DBACCF4C0301B02</RequestId>
   <HostId>
      raYVzr9xubG0NA/b57saIJzfc2YhnvhD0tafYmo34ewOBY6/0j1AKUFC/lEoY+6h
   </HostId>
</Error>
```

This happens for all names with the plus sign. What could be the problem. I've tried everything I could but nothing. This is my image_uploader class

```
# encoding: utf-8

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

   include CarrierWave::RMagick

   storage :fog

   include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
   process :set_content_type

   def store_dir
      "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.name.to_s.downcase.underscore || model.id.to_s.underscore.downcase}"
   end

   def filename
      "#{model.name.to_s.underscore.downcase}-#{secure_token}" if original_filename.present?
   end

   def default_url
      "fallback/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/" + [version_name, "noimage.gif"].compact.join('_')
   end

   version :nano_thumb do
       process :resize_to_fill => [20, 20]
   end

   version :mini_thumb do
       process :resize_to_fill => [25, 25]
   end

   version :small_thumb do
       process :resize_to_fill => [34, 34]
   end

   version :thumb do
      process :resize_to_fill => [48, 48]
   end

   version :small do
      process :resize_to_fill => [86, 86]
   end

   version :medium do
       process :resize_to_fill => [259, 259]
   end

   version :large do
       process :resize_to_fill => [518, 518]
   end

   def extension_white_list
      ["jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", ""]
   end

   protected
     def secure_token(length=9)
        var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
        model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.hex(length/2))
     end

  end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue in carrierwave which has been fixed on master but hasn't been released yet. Your options are:

1. Use carrierwave master instead of the official gem release.
2. Update the [sanitize_regexp](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave#filenames-and-unicode-chars) to exclude + characters.

   CarrierWave::SanitizedFile.sanitize_regexp = /[^a-zA-Z0-9.-_]/

New uploads will work with either of these, but you'll still have to fix old ones manually (dig through s3 to find the correct filename, then update your database). Or just delete them.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you incorrectly encode URL, as "+" sign must be URL-encoded first.

I would recommend you to run some sort of traffic analyzer tool ([Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) for example) and see what kind of traffic do you send to Amazon S3 server.

Hope it helps !

Comment: thanks its actually the gem `carrierwave` that doesn't properly encode the characters correctly.